# How to check if mysql connection its in a transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions

Is there a way to check if a MySQL transaction has begun?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598373/display-open-transactions-in-mysql

Comment: It is not a duplicate: "Transaction has begun..." and "Is there still an open transaction after failure etc." are two very different things