# SQL query with nested query on another table in it

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables, we'll call them email_bounces and master_email_list.

master_email_list is ~3.5m records.

email_bounces is ~100,000 records.

I'm trying to do a query where I update bounce=1 in master_email_list if the email address is found in email_bounces.

Here's what I have.

```
update 'master_email_list' set bounce=1 where email in (select email FROM 'email_bounces')
```

Except that doesn't seem to work, it queries, then hangs indefinitely (I left it running overnight, after about 4 hours running prior).

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an index on `master_email_list.email`?

Comment: Do you have an index on email in master_email_list and also in the bounces table? 
Also, try   update 'master_email_list' set bounce=1 where EXISTS (select 1 FROM 'email_bounces' B where M.email=B.email ) ... but you do need those indexes in place first.

Comment: For performance in MySQL, don't use a subquery in a predicate like that. Use a JOIN operation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
update master_email_list l
inner join email_bounces b on b.email = l.email
set bounce = 1
```

You could also try to deactivate keys during the update to speed things up:

```
ALTER TABLE master_email_list DISABLE KEYS;
```

And afterwards

```
ALTER TABLE master_email_list ENABLE KEYS;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using table **alias names** you have to set it.

In this i am using **inner join**

```
update master_email_list mel
   inner join email_bounces eb
     on mel.email = eb.email
     set mel.bounce = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If that simple query takes hours, I can only see two possible reasons;

- You're missing an index with `master_email_list.email` as a first column.

  CREATE INDEX ix_email ON master_email_list(email);

...should speed things up *significantly*.

- You have an active transaction on the table that holds a lock. Check that you have no uncommitted transactions pending, and if you can't find them, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7598932/477878) how to look for them.