# Error Code: 1192. Can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables or an active transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to truncate my table on mysql workbench

```
truncate pbx_api.confbridges;
```

but it says

```
Error Code: 1192. Can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables or an active transaction
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598373/display-open-transactions-in-mysql

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that the table is exclusively locked and is under transaction. You cannot truncate until it is rollbacked or committed.

For example to unlock tables, see @Cleber Griff's answer.

Answer (score 24):

I solved this problem using SQL query : `UNLOCK TABLES;`