# I use pymysql to execute query in MySQL, but why the process is still alive after I close the connection?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I use `pymysql` to connect mysql and I set a `read_timeout` when connecting:

```py
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,port=port,user=user,passwd=passwd,read_timeout=60)
```

and my query code is here:

```py
try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
except:
    # timeout
    logging.error()
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

When I execute a long time query, the code raise a timeout error and finally `cursor` and `connection` are both closed(I debug `conn._closed` to confirm the connection is closed).But when I login to mysql and `show processlist`, I found the process is still alive.

My question is, is this normal and How can I kill the process when query timeout in my code? I figure out a workaround that execute `set session max_execution_time=60` before query, but I think it's not the best practice.

Here is `show processlist` output, I use `sleep` to represent long time query, I think the result is the same, `connection` is closed in my code, but process is still there.

[show processlist output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCjO3.png)

Comment: Show the output from `show processlist`

Comment: hi @rdas  I've made a supplement

Comment: don't post text as image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_timeout` on PyMySQL connection objects is used as [timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) value on the underlying [socket](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L675) during read operations. If the timeout is reached, the socket raises a subclass of `OSError` ([socket.timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.timeout)), which is caught in the connection's [_read_bytes](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L680-L686) method.
 During the handling of that exception, [_force_close](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L371) is executed, which ultimately sets the `self._sock` attribute of the connection to `None`.

When your code reaches the `finally` block, all that is left to do during the execution of `conn.close()` is setting `_closed` to True.
If `_sock` was not `None` at this point, the `close` method would also attempt to send [`COM_QUIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-quit.html) to the server via the socket, but since the client-side socket is already closed, that does not happen.

From the server's point of view, the client wordlessly dropped the connection. Unfortunately, it's hard to find meaningful documentation on what exactly happens in that case.

Normally, on connection timeout, the pending transaction should be rolled back. However, I'm unsure if the client closing its socket would result in an immediate server-side timeout, as suggested in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598373/display-open-transactions-in-mysql). 
Also, using MySQL's `sleep` function for testing might be a bad idea. It could completely suspend the thread handling your connection and query, rendering it unable to detect the lost connection in time.

You might want to take a look at MySQL's [kill](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html) command, that is also implemented in the PyMySQL [connection](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L513), although undocumented. However, this will need an external timeout in your script when doing `cursor.execute` with statements that might take too long to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit the transaction before closing the connection. The process must be alive since the transaction has not been committed to the database.
Add `conn.autocommit=true` in the beginning  or during `conn` initialization,

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,port=port,user=user,passwd=passwd,read_timeout=60, autocommit=True)
```

Or, you can use `conn.commit()` before closing the connection.