# 2 mysql connections doesnt seem to update each other when doing data-manipulation

Tags: python, sql, mysql, multithreading, database-connection

So I have a python bot running that has 2 threads, each thread is using it's own database object to have a database connection towards a MySQL database. *I tried it with only one connection but received errors.*

So far so good.

The code nearly works fine and everything works as expected BUT my connection 1 SELECT statement doesn't seem to know that connection 2 updated a table. This is obviously a huge problem when handling 'world generation' like in my case in a different thread because the main application doesn't know that a new world had been generated.
Now I'm wondering why's that?

Here's an example Query that my connection 2 is executing

```
    def add_block_to_world(self, idWorld, idBlock, x, y):
        sql = f"SELECT idRel FROM worlds_has_blocks WHERE idWorld = {idWorld} AND x = {x} AND y = {y};"
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        res = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if res:
            # update the block
            sql = f"UPDATE worlds_has_blocks SET idBlock = {idBlock} WHERE idWorld = {idWorld} AND x = {x} AND y = {y};"
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            self.mydb.commit()
        else:
            # There doesn't exist a block yet
            sql = f"INSERT INTO worlds_has_blocks VALUE(NULL, {idWorld}, {idBlock}, {x}, {y});"
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            self.mydb.commit()
```

I've read a lot that I may be missing a commit or not, but I'm not. And If I read it correctly once I commit all other connections should receive the new edited columns?

here's my database constructor in case that's important.

```
class Database():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=config.botConfig["host"],
            user=config.botConfig["user"],
            password=config.botConfig["password"],
            port=config.botConfig["port"],
            database=config.botConfig["database"],
            charset='utf8mb4'
        )
        self.cursor = self.mydb.cursor()

        # Check if the connection is alive
        if self.mydb.is_connected():
            print("Database connection successful")
        else:
            print("Database connection failed")
```

below that are of course the methodes..

Any help? Can I somehow sync both connections? Is it something entirely I'm doing wrong with how I handle threads and mysql connections? Thanks.

Comment: There is probably an [open transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598373/how-to-display-open-transactions-in-mysql), which needs to be committed.  (see link to know how to display those open transactions)

Comment: 1) I would use an insert ... on duplicate key update ... instead of a select / update / insrt structure. 2) Your isolation level is probably on "repeatable read", which means the first select established the version of the data that a connection reads in. Try setting your isolation level to "read committed" to see updates done by concurrent transactions in a select.

Comment: That's true. My Isolation level was "repeatable read", I'll change that and see if it made a difference.
And also thanks for the other suggestion with duplicate key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue. The problem was that the session and global transaction isolation level was set to 'Repeatable Read'

Changing that to 'Read Commited' fixed the issue.
Thanks!